# How can I redirect to home page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I wonder how to set a redirection in .htaccess so that after entering my website jewelsandbeauty.co.uk the user will be directed directly to HOME (first item in the menu). Every redirect attempt ends with error 404. What is going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot say what "first item in the menu" actually means, what URL that resource has. Please take the time to revise your question, there is an "edit" button below it. Be specific: what URL do you actually want to redirect the client to? And what attempts have you actually tried? Please add your current attempt to the question. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to redirect https://jewelsandbeauty.co.uk to https://jewelsandbeauty.co.uk/home/

Comment: Then what keeps you from doing that? Why con't you use the "edit" button as mentioned? Why don't you add your attempts to the question?

Comment: Did you set your home page in Your homepage displays settings?
Go to wp-admin of your site settings-> reading -> Your homepage display.
Here you need to set the home page and save the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?$ /home/  [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com/home/` .

Comment: That is most likely not what is asked here.